# zsh: command not found: pip3.6

Tags: python, installation, python-3.6, fb-idb

I am trying to install IDB by following the official tutorial - [enter link description here](https://fbidb.io/docs/installation/). I have python 3.8 installed, I'm not much experienced with Python. I know when I want to run a python code I do issue pip3 and it still works on my mac, but according to the instruction on the page, it reads I should issue `pip3.6 install fb-idb` and I got this error `zsh: command not found: pip3.6`. How do I run this?

Comment: The 3.6 is a specific version of pip - if `pip install fb-idb` worked, it might all be ok.

Comment: I have installed it using pip3 but Appium doesn't see it when I run appium-doctor. I think that command is specific to make it work properly with Appium. How do I install pip3.6? Thanks.

Comment: `pip3.6` is specifically for python version `3.6`. You don't want to install that unless you are working with `python 3.6`.

Comment: If `python3 --version` refers to the version of python you care about (`3.8`), just use `python3 -m pip install fb-idb`.

Comment: Yes, it got installed previously but Appium isn't seeing it. I think it's pip3.6 specific to make it work with Appium.

Comment: By brief check, there is no reason the tutorial you link to requires 3.6. In fact just next to the instruction to run`pip`, it says 3.6 _or higher._

Comment: If you need help with Appium, ask about Appium instead.

Comment: just use pip3 install fb-idb, It worked for me